# fo-dicom how to set the default logging level

Tags: c#, fo-dicom

With the latest version of fo-dicom, how do you change the logging level to be > [DEBUG]?

Do you need to include the Dicom.Log from fo-dicom.Desktop? I've tried that and setting the LogManager to null as per instructions: https://github.com/fo-dicom/fo-dicom/wiki/Logging-configuration

But I'm still getting [DEBUG] and [INFO] printed to the console.

Ideally I'd like to have [DEBUG], [INFO] to log to file but only [FATAL] to console.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you figure this out?